# How to create Agent Pool in Azure DevOps via C# client?

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2019

How to create Agent Pool in Azure DevOps via C# client?

I find some raw rest api for agent pool [like this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/pools/add?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

But I want to create agent pool via C# client.

Now I use `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient` library, but can not find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need also the [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi](http://Install-Package%20Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi%20-Version%2016.153.0) nuget package:

```
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("URL"), new VssCredentials());
var client = connection.GetClient<TaskAgentHttpClient>();
client.AddAgentPoolAsync(new TaskAgentPool("TestPool"));
```

Comment: can you explane me, why i can not to create pool via c# - it says that i have no rights. I use this code. So, when i try to create Pool manual - i can do it!

Comment: Try to generate a PAT (personal access token) and use it the `VssCredentials`.